# How to fix 'click me' button to show and hide a certain window

Tags: javascript, html, css

My click me button is not working and it should do the following:

1. When you click the `<a>` tag makes the `.shade` area show up
2. when you click *anywhere* in the shaded area make the shade disappear

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.js-click-me');

button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let shade = event.querySelectorAll('shade.js-click-me');

    if (shade.style.display === 'none') {
        shade.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

```css
.shade {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="js-click-me">Click Me</a>
<div class="shade js-click-me">Show Me</div>
```

I expect when I click the button the .shade CSS should show and when I click the shaded area it should revert back to the first window.

Answer (score 2):

### OP's Code and explanations

I'll break down your JS:

```
let button = document.querySelector('.js-click-me');
```

Using `querySelector` will only return the first element that matches the query. In this case, that only matches your anchor tag.

```
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let shade = event.querySelectorAll('shade.js-click-me');

    if (shade.style.display === 'none') {
        shade.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

So here you're only adding the event listener to the first a tag. Then you're passing in the `event` object which is an instance of `MouseEvent`, which doesn't have a method called `querySelectorAll`. That only exists on HTML Elements, or on the document itself. In this case you'd want to just use `document.querySelector` since you're referencing the main scope of the document and you only want to select one single element. You missed the preceding `.` before referencing your `.shade.js-click-me` element as well.

Also, the content of your function only ever tries to toggle one way: if it's hidden, show it. If you want it to toggle both ways, you'll need the eventListener on both elements, and you'll have to check "if hidden, show OR if shown, hide".

Finally, `shade.style.display` will not be === to `none` to start even though your CSS includes it. that `style` property only references anything inside the inline `style` property of an element, like `<div class="shade" style="display: none"></div>`. What you'll need instead is `window.getComputedStyle(shade).display`.

### Working Example

Run the snippet below to see how it all comes together.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-click-me');

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
    let shade = document.querySelector('.shade');
    const display = window.getComputedStyle(shade).display;
    shade.style.display = display === 'none' ? 'block' : '';
  });
}
```

```css
.shade {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: #444;
color: #fff;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="js-click-me">
Click Me </a>
<div class="shade js-click-me">
Show Me</div>
```

Comment: `shade.style.display === 'none'` will work if we set the display property in inline style. but we are getting display property value from a class (.shades)....  your logic is good, but only in display property is an inline property

Comment: @DupinderSingh that's exactly what I said, which is why I suggested switching to `window.getComputedStyle`. That will return whichever display value is actively applied to the element, no matter if it's a user agent, class, or inline styling.

Comment: Yaa i got it, please mark some updations, so i can upvote it. and thanks, its working perfectly fine, Clear my doubts too. thanks

Comment: I know this is complete answer, but i want to upvote, But System doesn't allows me, it show me the alert, please update answer to upvote, So i want to add some spaces or somethoing else, so that i can upvote the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192339/discussion-between-dupinder-singh-and-scrimothy).

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle the class name if you want. like:

```
<button id="myBtn">Try it (Click Me)</button>
<div id="myDIV">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

```
.shade {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
const btn = getElementById("myBtn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  const element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.

First of all, You're using `querySelectorAll` to target the `shade` class inside the eventListener. This returns all elements with the given class as an array, even if there's only one element. If this is intentional, you have to iterate through all the elements, then removing/adding the styling. If this isn't intentional, replace it with `querySelector`, so it only returns a single element.

You're also missing a `.` in your selector parameter. I believe it should say be `.shade.js-click-me`.

I'd suggest using a class to add and remove the `display` property of the `.shade` element. It'd be something like:

```css
.shade--hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Remember to remove the `display: none` from inside the `shade` class. With this class, you can add and remove it inside your event listener as you please, thus toggling the shade display state:

```js
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let shade = event.querySelector('.shade.js-click-me');

    if (shade.classList.contains('shade--hidden'))
        shade.classList.remove('shade--hidden');
})
```

I created a quick codepen with the changes listed above:
https://codepen.io/Phoenix1355/pen/PgxKwG?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

```js
let shade = document.querySelector(".shade")
let clickme = document.querySelector(".click-me")

clickme.addEventListener("click", event => {
 shade.classList.toggle("toggle")
});

shade.addEventListener("click", event => {
 shade.classList.toggle('toggle')
});
```

```css
.shade {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.toggle {
 display: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="click-me">Click Me</a>
<div class="shade toggle">Show Me</div>
```